# How to change the value inside the column and underline it?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a form to enter scores and calculate the average score. After entering the form, the user clicks on the submit button, it will display a table of scores that have been entered before along with 2 buttons but the average score column must show the value "?". Then, when user click the "Calculate the average score" button will calculate the average scores and replace the "?" value, the "Best student" button will determine if any average score is >= 8 the letter in that column will be highlighted in red. My problem is how to calculate the average score and replace the "?" value, moreover how to determine if any average score is >= 8 the letter in that column will be highlighted in red. I am really appreciate for your help.

Here is my code.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project 3 - Jquery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <body>
        <h1 align="center" class="col- col-s-12 col-12">Class Marksheet</h1>

        <!--Form for users to enter scores-->
        <table align="center" class="col- col-s-3 col-3">
          <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Math:</td>
            <td>
              <input name="math" min="0" max="10" id="math" type="number" />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Physics:</td>
            <td>
              <input
                name="physics"
                min="0"
                max="10"
                id="physics"
                type="number"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Chemistry:</td>
            <td>
              <input
                name="chemical"
                min="0"
                max="10"
                id="chemical"
                type="number"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <td>
            <button type="submit" id="show_table">Submit</button>
          </td>
        </table>

        <!--After the user enters the score and click the submits button this table will be displayed with the 2 buttons below-->
        <div id="divTable">
          <table
            id="tableScore"
            class="col- col-s-12 col-12"
            border="5"
            align="center"
          >
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Math</th>
            <th>Physics</th>
            <th>Chemistry</th>
            <th>Average Score</th> <!--This column will display the value "?"-->
          </table>

          <!--Click this button to calculate the average score and replace the value "?"-->
          <button  id="showAvg" align="center">
            Calculate the average score
          </button>

          <!--Determine if any average score is >= 8 the letter in that column will be highlighted in red-->
          <button id="showBest" align="center">
            Best student
          </button>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
var testScore = { 
    name: "",
    math: 0,
    physical: 0,
    chemistry: 0,
    avg: 0
};

var i = 1;

// This will display the table and the average score has "?" value
$(function() {
    $('#show_table').click(function() {
        $('#divTable').css("display","block");
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var math = $("#math").val();
        var physics = $("#physics").val();
        var chemical = $("#chemical").val();
        $('#divTable').css("display","block");
        
        $("#name").val("");
        $("#math").val("");
        $("#physics").val("");
        $("#chemical").val("");

        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + math + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + physics + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + chemical + "</td>";
        html +=  "<td>?</td>";

        
        $('#divTable table').append(html);
        i++;
    });
});

// I need help to calculate the average score and replace "?" value

// And if any average score >= 8 the letter will be red.
```

CSS File:

```
#divTable {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-s-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-s-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-s-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-s-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-s-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-s-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-s-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-s-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-s-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-s-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-s-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add classes to score and average so you can target those elements with jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#show_table').click(function() {
        $('#divTable').css("display","block");
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var math = $("#math").val();
        var physics = $("#physics").val();
        var chemical = $("#chemical").val();
        $('#divTable').css("display","block");
        
        $("#name").val("");
        $("#math").val("");
        $("#physics").val("");
        $("#chemical").val("");

        var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
        html += "<td class='score'>" + math + "</td>";
        html += "<td class='score'>" + physics + "</td>";
        html += "<td class='score'>" + chemical + "</td>";
        html +=  "<td class='average'>?</td>";

        
        $('#divTable table').append(html);
        i++;
    });
    $('#showAvg').click(function() {
       var $scores = $('#divTable').find('.score');
       var score = $scores.map(function() {
          return parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
       }).reduce(function(sum, score) {
          return sum + score;
       }, 0);
       var average = score / $scores.length;
       $('.average').html(average);
    });
});
```